# Python transpose sqlite table

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I have an sqlite database with a table organized like:

itemdata

```
date_time       | item_code | value

3/13/2015 12:23 | fridge21  | 345.45
3/13/2015 12:23 | heater12  | 12.34
3/13/2015 12:23 | fan02     | 63.78
3/13/2015 12:24 | fridge21  | 345.47
```

I would like to retrieve the data in the itemdata table to be like:

```
date_time | fridge21 | heater12 | fan02 

3/13/2015 12:23 | 345.45 | 12.34 | 63.78
3/13/2015 12:24 | 345.47 | 12.45 | 63.23
```

I have tried:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_NAME)  
sql = "SELECT * FROM {0}".format(table_name)
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.T, columns=df.columns)
```

But I don't want to exactly transpose the itemdata table (which has 1x10^6 rows and 3 columns), I want to a unique item_codes column only as per the desired output above.

Any hints on how to do this?

Comment: How many unique items are there in database as you can run a conditional aggregate query, the classic way to pivot SQL data?

Comment: @Parfait only 50 unique items so could work fine, but aggregate queries seem to be for things such as avg, count https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html , how would you apply in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pivot` against a raw dataframe that loads the sqllite table:

```
df.pivot('date_time', 'item_code', 'value')
```

Comment: this looks like it's on the right track. however I get an indexerror on df.pivot(...) ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape and a typeerror on df.pivot_table(...) TypeError: pivot_table() got multiple values for argument 'values'

Comment: I tested the trial data here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html and your solution worked OK so must be a problem with my data

Comment: If you have dupes on a given axis, you can also consider using pivot_table instead: that function will give you more parameters like aggfunc to aggregate dupe data and do a mean for instance